# Android: Issue setting image using Html.ImageGetter

Tags: image, email, drawable, html-email

I'm having trouble using `Html.ImageGetter` to replace `<img>` place-holders in my email html body text.

I'm using a custom ImageGetter class `UnivImageGetter` and calling `Html.fromHtml(htmlBodyText, new UnivImageGetter(context), null)` to set the email text, but for some reason, the image is still not being displayed in the email body. It just shows an empty box with `OBJ` in the middle.

I am able to verify that the correct Drawable is returned from my custom ImageGetter class `UnivImageGetter.getDrawable()`, so that is not the issue.

I've been researching this all day and no luck so far. 
Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!